# Is it possible to find out what is leaking GDI Objects

Tags: c++, c++builder, gdi

I have an application in **Embarcadera RAD Studio 2010 (C++)**. Is it possible to peek into it to see what would be leaking GDI Objects? A tree structured menu is leaking GDI Objects when text is set to **Bold**. My guess is that the "original" text is first created and then an instance where it is in bold and the first one is "forgotten about" and leaked.

EDIT: Since no leak is reported usin AQTime, even though is obvoius by looking at Taskmanager, I traced the snippet of code that is creating and not releasing GDI Objects.

```
...

Msg.WParam=(int)PhysicalListView->Canvas->Handle;
PhysicalListView->Dispatch(&Msg);

...
```

**PhysicalListView** is a pointer to a **TListView**. As I understand it the classes that start with **T** is part of the standard Embarcadero classes (correct?).

When I have selected a node in the listview with children that have undecorated text everything works fine. But when one, or more, of the children have *bold* or *underlined* text for example the GDI count does not decrease after the Dispatch call.

So my guess is that this is an error in the **TListView** class. I don't know if this works against WinForms or if it uses it's own solution?

Also, this occurs in Debug mode. I will check if the problem goes away when compiling a release build. If so it indicates a leak in the debug versions of **TListView**.

EDIT2: I think I have uncovered the problem. The initial message sent included a **WM_PAINT** and after reading about it this message should not be sent by a client application but is instead used by the system. So I changed this to a **WM_PRINT** and the leak went away. I don't know why a **WM_PAINT** was used, prehaps I'm missing some functionality of it... Any ideas why they would have used **WM_PAINT**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AQTime is my tool of choice. It's a profiler and brings many more features than just GDI leak detection. RAD Studio XE comes with the Standard version of AQTime. For the Pro version you need to pay more.

Comment: I can't seem to find it. Doesn't seem to be installed. Checked on the "Partner ISO" to but nothing there either... hmmmm

Comment: I installed the trial, but I don't get it to list any GDI information :)... I select the "Resource Profiler" and select "GDI" and "GDI+" but I just get an empty report, except for som errors in `user32.dll`, "user32.dll 1411 GetClassInfoW Class does not exist."

Comment: @inquam: IIRC it got installed by default without partner ISO (but that's XE, as I wrote). The "Resource Profiler" is the correct one, but you also need to make sure that you are sampling. Otherwise it would explain why there is no output. Hard to guess what exactly is wrong. But I've had good results with AQTime on different Windows versions. For unixoid systems Valgrind is usually spot on with leaks.

Comment: I have set it up exactly like this: http://smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/18053/

But I don't get to see any leaks regarding GDI. But I can see in the taskmanager that it's clearly leaking like crazy.

Comment: @inquam: so you run the program from start to end (exit) and see no leaks? Well, that usually means there are none. Task manager is not a reliable means to find out about leaks, though.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: Look at my latest edit. I found and fixed the "leak".

Comment: @inquam: okay, great. Yes WM_PAINT is indeed not meant to be sent by the application under normal circumstances. But there are some valid reasons to do it. If you need something custom, define a name yourself and use one out of the WM_APP or WM_USER ranges as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [GdiUsage.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/msdnmag/issues/03/01/GDILeaks/default.aspx)?

http://discuss.fogcreek.com/dotnetquestions/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=5037&ixReplies=5

Comment: Just read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301756.aspx
Will give it a go and see

Answer (score 2):

[Memory Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/cpp/memory/index.html) is a tool we use at work, which handles all types of memory leaks, including gdi objects.